# Handle while loop in different classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, while-loop

I have two classes inside which i have one function which prints counting of number. Inside both classes i am using while True.

TRIAL 1:-

```
first.py -
class first:
    count = 0
    def firstm(self):
        while True:
            print("First Class Method : ",self.count)
second.py -
class second:
    count = 0
    def secondm(self):
        while True:
            print("Second Class Method : ",self.count)

 run.py -  
 from first import first
 from second import second

 class run:
     def runmethod(self):
        while True:
            first().firstm()
            second().secondm()

run().runmethod()

Output -
    First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5
First Class : 6
First Class : 7
First Class : 8
First Class : 9
    First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5
First Class : 6
First Class : 7
First Class : 8
First Class : 9
    First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5

Here it keep on repeating the first class method only.
```

In the above code the program only runs for the first class firstm method. It won't goto next class.

Trial 2 :-

```
first.py -
class first:
    count = 0
    @classmethod
    def firstm(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("First Class Method : ",self.count)

second.py -
class second:
    @classmethod
    def secondm(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("Second Class Method : ",i)

run.py- 
from first import first
from second import second

class run:
    def runmethod(self):
        while True:
            first.firstm()
            second.secondm()

run().runmethod()

Output -
First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5
First Class : 6
First Class : 7
First Class : 8
First Class : 9
Second Class : 0
Second Class : 1    
Second Class : 2
Second Class : 3
Second Class : 4
Second Class : 5
Second Class : 6
Second Class : 7
Second Class : 8
Second Class : 9
Third Class : 0
Third Class : 1
Third Class : 2
Third Class : 3
Third Class : 4
Third Class : 5
Third Class : 6
Third Class : 7
Third Class : 8
Third Class : 9
Fourth Class : 0
Fourth Class : 1
Fourth Class : 2
Fourth Class : 3
Fourth Class : 4
Fourth Class : 5
Fourth Class : 6
Fourth Class : 7
Fourth Class : 8
Fourth Class : 9
After this it won't print anything
```

In the second trial it only runs the code once and then stops.

Trial 3:-

```
first.py -
class first:
    count = 0
    def firstm(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("First Class Method : ",self.count)

second.py -
class second:
    def secondm(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("Second Class Method : ",i)

run.py-
from first import first
from second import second

class run:
    def runmethod(self):
        while True:
            first().firstm()
            second().secondm()

run().runmethod()

Output - 
First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5
First Class : 6
First Class : 7
First Class : 8
First Class : 9
Second Class : 0
Second Class : 1    
Second Class : 2
Second Class : 3
Second Class : 4
Second Class : 5
Second Class : 6
Second Class : 7
Second Class : 8
Second Class : 9
Third Class : 0
Third Class : 1
Third Class : 2
Third Class : 3
Third Class : 4
Third Class : 5
Third Class : 6
Third Class : 7
Third Class : 8
Third Class : 9
Fourth Class : 0
Fourth Class : 1
Fourth Class : 2
Fourth Class : 3
Fourth Class : 4
Fourth Class : 5
Fourth Class : 6
Fourth Class : 7
Fourth Class : 8
Fourth Class : 9
    First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5
First Class : 6
First Class : 7
First Class : 8
First Class : 9
Second Class : 0
Second Class : 1    
Second Class : 2
Second Class : 3
Second Class : 4
Second Class : 5
Second Class : 6
Second Class : 7
Second Class : 8
Second Class : 9
Third Class : 0
Third Class : 1
Third Class : 2
Third Class : 3
Third Class : 4
Third Class : 5
Third Class : 6
Third Class : 7
Third Class : 8
Third Class : 9
Fourth Class : 0
Fourth Class : 1
Fourth Class : 2
Fourth Class : 3
Fourth Class : 4
Fourth Class : 5
Fourth Class : 6
Fourth Class : 7
Fourth Class : 8
Fourth Class : 9
First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5
First Class : 6
First Class : 7
First Class : 8
First Class : 9
Second Class : 0
Second Class : 1    
Second Class : 2
Second Class : 3
Second Class : 4
Second Class : 5
Second Class : 6
Second Class : 7
Second Class : 8
Second Class : 9
Third Class : 0
Third Class : 1
Third Class : 2
Third Class : 3
Third Class : 4
Third Class : 5
Third Class : 6
Third Class : 7
Third Class : 8
Third Class : 9
Fourth Class : 0
Fourth Class : 1
Fourth Class : 2
Fourth Class : 3
Fourth Class : 4
Fourth Class : 5
Fourth Class : 6
Fourth Class : 7
Fourth Class : 8
Fourth Class : 9
First Class : 0
First Class : 1
First Class : 2
First Class : 3
First Class : 4
First Class : 5
First Class : 6
First Class : 7
First Class : 8
First Class : 9
Second Class : 0
Second Class : 1    
Second Class : 2
Second Class : 3
```

In the third trial i am getting output correctly but it creates many objects of both classes.

What i am trying to do is once the run().runmethod() runs it first goto first class then execute firstm method.
Then it go to second class and execute secondm method. Upon finish of secondm method it again goto first class firstm method and do the execution.

Please tell me how to handle it or is there any better way to do it.

Comment: In your first set of code, the methods contain infinite loops. `firstm()` never returns, so it never calls `secondm()`.

Comment: If you tell Python to do one thing forever, then do another thing forever afterwards, Python isn't going to get around to the second thing.

Comment: @Barmar Sir thats why in below code i replaced while loop with  for loop

Comment: Where is `firstm()` defined in the last code block?

Comment: @user2357112 Sir i realized my mistake in Trial 1 so i changed the code in Trial 2 & 3 but still its not giving the result i wanted.

Comment: @Barmar  Sir while typing the question i did that mistake. I corrected the question

Comment: I don't see why the second trial only runs the code once. You have an infinite loop with `while True:`.

Comment: @Barmar  Sir its won't print anything after executing second.secondm() in Trial- 2

Comment: When I do trial 2, it prints `First Class Method :  0` 10 times, then it prints `Second Class Method :  0` through `Second Class Method :  9`, then it repeats this infinitely.

Comment: I had to fix the first `def secondm` to `def firstm` in trial 2.

Comment: There's no `second().secondm()` in Trial 2, it's just `second.secondm()`. Are you sure you're running the same code as the question? All those copying errors make me think you're not.

Comment: @Barmar  Sir what fix you did because for me i am not getting any output after Second Class Method : 9

Comment: All I did was change `def secondm` to `def firstm` in the `first` class.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for my mistake sir. It is second.secondm() in Trial - 2

Comment: The error was: `AttributeError: type object 'first' has no attribute 'firstm'`

Comment: Maybe you should post the output you're trying to get.

Comment: @Barmar Ok sir.

Comment: @Barmar It took some time to paste the output sir. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Barmar I think i am taking the wrong approch to achive the result. Sir is there any better way to do it

Comment: Where does the`Third Class` and `Fourth Class` output come from? And why is the number increasing in First Class, when you just print `self.counter`, which is always `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Trial-1 we can use count variable to control the number of times the while loop run.
We can increment the count variable of each class and run the class only till the time a certain condition is True. 
Once the condition is false we can get out of the class.

```
first.py -
class first:
    count = 0
    def firstm(self):
        while self.count<10:
            print("First Class Method : ",self.count)
            self.count = self.count+1
second.py -
class second:
    count = 0
    def secondm(self):
        while self.count<10:
            print("Second Class Method : ",self.count)
            self.count = self.count+1

run.py -  
from first import first
from second import second

 class run:
     def runmethod(self):
        while True:
            first().firstm()
            second().secondm()

run().runmethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this for the third block of code. It should get you what you want.

```
class run:
    def runmethod(self):
        for i in range(2):
            first().firstm()
            if i == 1:
                break
            second().secondm()
```

Comment: Why even do a loop? Just `first().firstm(); second().secondm(); first.firstm()`

Comment: Great idea. Thought of it too but you know, software engineering rules.
DRY- Don't Repeat Yourself.
It really wouldn't matter in this case though. I was just thinking of scaling. What if some more functions come into play later?

Answer (score 0):

`first.firstm()` is always printing `0` because you never increment `self.counter`. Other than that, your Trial 2 code should work as intended.

```
#first.py -
class first:
    count = 0
    @classmethod
    def firstm(self):
        self.count = 0
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("First Class Method : ",self.count)
            self.count += 1

#second.py -
class second:
    @classmethod
    def secondm(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("Second Class Method : ",i)

#run.py
from first import first
from second import second

class run:
    def runmethod(self):
        while True:
            first.firstm()
            second.secondm()

run().runmethod()
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/tQiIdv)

In the demo I changed `while True:` to `for _ in range(0, 3):` so the demo will end quickly.

If you want to use object methods instead of class methods (Trial 3), but don't want to create a new object each time through the loop, you can do it by creating the objects before the loop.

```
class run:
    def runmethod(self):
        f = first()
        s = second()
        while True:
            f.firstm()
            s.secondm()
```